# Channel Estimation of OFDM using Long training Sequences

Tags: ofdm, channel

Based on IEEE 802.11a Standards, I am using two Training Sequence-Preamble for Synchronization and Channel estimation.
I have read in some papers that the channel estimation is performed by taking the mean of both received identical sequences of Long training Preamble (each of length 64 samples) and multiply the result with the known Long training sequence (make all of them equal to 53 samples by removing the null-subcarriers).

H[i] = (LTS_1_Rx[i] + LTS_2_Rx[i])/2 * L[i],         i=[-26, 26]

I have also try to take one of the received Long sequence (64 samples) and divide it by the known Long sequence (resize them to 53 samples by removing the null-subcarriers).

My questions are:

1. What is the best method to estimate the channel of ofdm signal in terms of using long sequence Preamble!
2. If both received Long sequences are used for channel estimation, are they the ones obtained after coarse and fine frequency offset correction! If yes, then channel estimate will lose the effect of phase offset and will only show the effect of magnitude effect!
3. What is the best way to display the channel frequency response (absolute of the channel magnitude or Magnitude with phase!).

I have attach a photo of my channel estimate (Channel frequency response) taken by dividing one of the received long sequence after phase offset correction with the known Long sequence (53 samples) for your information.

Thank you in advance.

[image]